# Move OWA to new URL

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

I have a single Exchange 2010 server running all roles. OWA is currently configured for the url https://owa.currentwebsite/owa

I'm trying to work out how to move OWA to https://owa.newwebsite/owa

Does anyone know of a guide on how to do this?

What I've done so far.

Created a new zone in public DNS for new website.

Created A record for OWA in new zone

Created SRV record for autodiscover in new zone

Created MX records in new zone

Installed new SSL cert onto Exchange server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that all that is required now is to change the URL using powershell and bounce IIS:

```
Get-OWAVirtualDirectory -Server MyCASServer | Set-OWAVirtualDirectory -InternalURL https://owa.newsite.com/owa -ExternalURL https://owa.newsite.com/owa

IISreset -noforce
```